# How to derive the maximum *a posteriori* estimate when the prior distribution is Normal $N(m,r^2)$?

Tags: machine-learning, probability, normal-distribution, maximum-likelihood, posterior

I am learning probabilities and I need a guru to help with this problem:

Assume $p(y | x) = N(ax,\ s^2)$, where all quantities are scalars, $a$ and $s$ are known constants, and the prior distribution over $x$ is $N(m,\ r^2)$, where $m$ and $r$ are known constants.

The maximum *a posteriori* (MAP) estimate is the value of $x$ that maximizes $$P(x | y) = \frac{P( y | x) P(x)}{P(y)}.$$

You observe $y_1,..., y_N$. How do you derive the maximum *a posteriori* estimate of $x$?

Comment: Usually the MAP of X is when you have X that is an RV, but is distributed according to some Theta parameter, over which there also exists a distribution, it's not clear if this is what you're trying to understand, or whether you're looking for X|Y

Comment: Two hints to get started: 1) $P(y)$ in the denominator is constant so it doesn't affect the solution and can be disregarded. You can just maximize the numerator. 2) You can equivalently maximize the log of the numerator (the solution will be the same because the log is a monotonic function). This will be more convenient to work with.